# Bat job not reading txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I wrote that performs a WMI query to obtain the mounted drives, and output that data to a local text file.  The resulting text file is 46B, while a file file created in notepad with the same data is only 22B.

When I use the `type` command, i can output the contents of the file, but I have not found any other way.  Below is the code that I finally got to work, by outputting the `type` command to a new text file.

Any idea what is happening here?

```
wmic logicaldisk where "caption >= 'H:' and caption <= 'Q:'" get caption > c:\drive.txt

type drive.txt > driveNew.txt

del drive.txt /f /q

for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (driveNew.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"

"C:\Program Files\RemoveDrive\x64\RemoveDrive.exe" %line% -L

del driveNew.txt /f /q
```

Comment: Wmic have an unicode output !

Comment: @sachadee Put this in an answer and I will accept it.  It is encoded UCS-2 Little Endian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wmic have an unicode output that's why you have to do that to get a correct value !

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper text editor with hex-display facilites. You're likely to find that thw `WMIC` output has <CR> characters without a <LF> following. Plays havoc.